# NotImplementedError: `fit_generator` is not yet enabled for Model subclasses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a vehicle damage detection model following the blogpost
https://narender-reddy.medium.com/car-body-damage-detection-u-net-u-net-implementation-a-case-study-759b408e2c1f with my own dataset (also annotated with the VIA Tool).
I used the Modified Unet Architecture, which is defined as follows:

```
# Modified u-net model
class EncoderBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, filter_size):
    # initilize instance variables
    super(EncoderBlock, self).__init__()
    self.filter_size = filter_size
    # define layers
    self.layer_1 = layers.Activation('relu')
    self.layer_2 = layers.SeparableConv2D(self.filter_size, 3, padding='same')
    self.layer_3 = layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.layer_4 = layers.Activation('relu')
    self.layer_5 = layers.SeparableConv2D(self.filter_size, 3, padding='same')
    self.layer_6 = layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.layer_7 = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')

    # project residual
    self.residual_layer = layers.Conv2D(self.filter_size, 1, strides=2, padding='same')
  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.layer_1(inputs)
    x = self.layer_2(x)
    x = self.layer_3(x)
    x = self.layer_4(x)
    x = self.layer_5(x)
    x = self.layer_6(x)
    x = self.layer_7(x)
    residual = self.residual_layer(inputs)
    x = layers.add([x, residual])
    return x

class DecoderBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, filter_size):
    # initilize instance variables
    super(DecoderBlock, self).__init__()
    self.filter_size = filter_size
    # define layers
    self.layer_1 = layers.Activation('relu')
    self.layer_2 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(self.filter_size, 3, padding='same')
    self.layer_3 = layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.layer_4 = layers.Activation('relu')
    self.layer_5 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(self.filter_size, 3, padding='same')
    self.layer_6 = layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.layer_7 = layers.UpSampling2D(2)

    # project residual
    self.residual_layer_1 = layers.UpSampling2D(2)
    self.residual_layer_2 = layers.Conv2D(filter_size, 1, padding='same')
  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.layer_1(inputs)
    x = self.layer_2(x)
    x = self.layer_3(x)
    x = self.layer_4(x)
    x = self.layer_5(x)
    x = self.layer_6(x)
    x = self.layer_7(x)
    residual = self.residual_layer_1(inputs)
    residual = self.residual_layer_2(residual)

    x = layers.add([x, residual])
    return x

class UnetModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, output_channels, dynamic=True):
    # initilize instance variables
    super(UnetModel, self).__init__()
    self.output_channels = output_channels
    
    self.entry_block_1 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, input_shape=(128, 128, 3),strides=2, padding='same')
    self.entry_block_2 = layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.entry_block_3 = layers.Activation('relu')

    self.encoder_block_1 = EncoderBlock(64)
    self.encoder_block_2 = EncoderBlock(128)
    self.encoder_block_3 = EncoderBlock(256)

    self.decoder_block_1 = DecoderBlock(256)
    self.decoder_block_2 = DecoderBlock(128)
    self.decoder_block_3 = DecoderBlock(64)
    self.decoder_block_4 = DecoderBlock(32)

    self.output_layer = layers.Conv2D(
        output_channels, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
    
  def call(self, inputs):
    
    
    x = self.entry_block_1(inputs)
    x = self.entry_block_2(x)
    x = self.entry_block_3(x)
    x = self.encoder_block_1(x)
    x = self.encoder_block_2(x)
    x = self.encoder_block_3(x)
    x = self.decoder_block_1(x)
    x = self.decoder_block_2(x)
    x = self.decoder_block_3(x)
    x = self.decoder_block_4(x)
    x = self.output_layer(x)
    return x
```

Because my dataset is limited, I used a the ImageDataGenerator() and tried to run the model with fit_generator:

```
model = UnetModel(OUTPUT_CHANNELS)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=sm.losses.dice_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
model_history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=EPOCHS,
                          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                          validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
                          validation_data=val_generator,
                          callbacks=[DisplayCallback()])
```

Somehow I keep getting the Error:

```
NotImplementedError: `fit_generator` is not yet enabled for Model subclasses
```

I use tensorflow-gpu version 1.7.1 and keras version 2.1.0 .

EDIT:

The code for the data generators is as follows:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

# Creating the training Image and Mask generator
image_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.5, rotation_range=50, zoom_range=0.2, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, fill_mode='reflect')
mask_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.5, rotation_range=50, zoom_range=0.2, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, fill_mode='reflect')

# Keep the same seed for image and mask generators so they fit together

image_datagen.fit(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen.fit(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)], augment=True, seed=seed)

x=image_datagen.flow(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)
y=mask_datagen.flow(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)



# Creating the validation Image and Mask generator
image_datagen_val = image.ImageDataGenerator()
mask_datagen_val = image.ImageDataGenerator()

image_datagen_val.fit(X_train[int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9):], augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen_val.fit(Y_train[int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9):], augment=True, seed=seed)

x_val=image_datagen_val.flow(X_train[int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9):],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)
y_val=mask_datagen_val.flow(Y_train[int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9):],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)

train_generator = zip(x, y)
val_generator = zip(x_val, y_val)
```

EDIT2:
I also tried the following for a workaround (@Yefet's suggestion):

```
image_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.5, rotation_range=50, zoom_range=0.2, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, fill_mode='reflect')

train_datagen=image_datagen.flow(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)] ,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)

# Creating the validation Image and Mask generator
image_datagen_val = image.ImageDataGenerator()

val_datagen=image_datagen_val.flow(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)] ,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)
```

with

```
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=EPOCHS,
                          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                          validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
                          validation_data=val_generator,
                          callbacks=[DisplayCallback()])
```

but I get  `ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=<keras.preprocessing.image.NumpyArrayIterator object at 0x7f9907f74438>`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try using model.fit() simply and tell me what happen

Comment: Then I get ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=<zip object at 0x7f4e91bc4908>

Comment: show me code for generators

Comment: @Yefet edited my post accordingly

Comment: instead of x and y alone can you try combine : train_datagen=image_datagen.flow(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], (Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)] ,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)
and then model.fit(train_datagen) and tell me what happen

Comment: @Yefet I added your suggestion to my Post. I am not quite sure whether I was doing it right, could you maybe have a look at it? I get a ValueError as stated above in the post.

Comment: your unet model just worked for me using my own generator , to make thing clear for you and me how your images are structed? under a folder for train and test or dataframe?

Comment: @Yefet They are structured folderwise, it's strange bc with other models it worked just fine. Which keras and tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: @Yefet I am creating the masks (dimension (128,128,1)) from the annotation json file from VIA. The images have three color channels.

Comment: so you have train image and under it a folder for each classes with correspodant images? right

Comment: @Yefet No, I iterate over different folders, each containing 5-10 images and the VIA annotatioin file containing the class and read it following this code https://github.com/nitsourish/car-damage-detection-using-CNN/blob/master/custom_1.py

Comment: the problm comes from your dataloader is hard for me to reproduce it cuz i used my own dataloader to fit but from keras documenation they use x and y on same flow can you check the "flow" part of this link : https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/